# How can i load item from a listBox as file and show the file content?

Tags: c#

I have this Code in Form1. Im doing a search for xml files. When i find them im using listBox1 selected index changed event and i want to do that when i select item in the lixtBox it will consider it as a file will parse it content and show me the parsed content.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.XPath;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        DirectoryInfo dirinf = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\");
        List<FileSystemInfo> fsi = new List<FileSystemInfo>();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
            button1.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void ParseAndDisplayXml(string filename)
        {
            XDocument document = XDocument.Load(filename);
            var list = document.Root.Elements("Message")
                .Select(
                e => new
                {
                    Date = e.Attribute("Date").Value.ToString(),
                    Time = e.Attribute("Time").Value.ToString(),
                    Text = e.Element("Text").Value.ToString()
                }
                );
 string result="";
            foreach (var item in list)
            {
               result += string.Format("Date--{0},Time--{1},Text--{2}", item.Date, item.Time, item.Text + Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }




        public void Search(string strExtension,
                            DirectoryInfo di,
                            List<FileSystemInfo> pResult)
        {
            try
            {

                foreach (FileInfo fi in di.GetFiles())
                {
                    if (InvokeRequired)
                    {
                        BeginInvoke(new Action(() => label2.Text = fi.Name));
                    }
                    if (fi.Name == "MessageLog.xsl")
                    {
                        foreach (FileInfo fii in di.GetFiles())
                        {
                        if (fii.Extension == strExtension)
                            pResult.Add(fii);
                        }
                        if (InvokeRequired)
                        {
                            BeginInvoke(new Action(() => label4.Text = pResult.Count.ToString() + Environment.NewLine));
                        }

                    }
                }

                    foreach (DirectoryInfo diChild in di.GetDirectories())
                        Search(strExtension, diChild, pResult);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            }
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            Search(".xml", dirinf, fsi);
            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(100);

        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < fsi.Count; i++)
            {                
                    listBox1.Items.Add(fsi[i].Name + Environment.NewLine);
            }


        }

        private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label2.Text = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        }            
    }
}
```

Im starting the search from C:\ 
Then when the search so over completed im adding the items it found to the listBox1.

For example now in my listBox1 i have 4 files:

danny.xml
adi.xml
sharon.xml
yoval.xml

In the selectedindexchanged i added option so the user can move between the items.

Now what i want to do is when the user select some index for example index [1] in the listBox and only if he clicked enter with the keyboard or clicked with the mouse left click it will call/use the function: ParseAndDisplayXML.

Then it will parse the selected index wich need to be translated to a file so in the backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted event i madding the files to the listBox as items but only with the names of the files. If i did .FullName instead .Name it was adding the files names with the directories too.

So i need somehow to get the FullName of the files in the completed event i think then when selecting one of the FullName items to parse it and display it in the listBox.

The parse function should take the specific content from the xml files and it worked i checked this function before alone.

The problem is how do i make that the user will select the index by click/key enter and how to parse and display it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add something to a listbox.
It expects an object, and sets the text to object.ToString()

e.g.

```
MyListBox.Add(100);
```

Would box 100 and display "100"

Couldn't find if  FileSystemInfo's ToString() method has been overridden but first thing to try would be

```
private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender,
RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
// newline is unnecesary and you should be using foreach
  foreach(FileSystemInfo f in fsi)
  {                
    listBox1.Items.Add(f);
  }
}
// display full name of file
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  label2.Text = ((FileSystemInfo)listBox1.SelectedItem).Fullname;
}
```

If FileSystemInfo.ToString() doesn't return Name, there are a few ways to deal with that.
If you don't want to hold on to the FileSystemInfo instances, we can deal with that too.